# Determining Primary Keys from ODBC Openedge 10.2B

Tags: yii2, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I am currently in the process of implementing an ActiveRecord driver for Yii2 such that I could leverage my progress databases in my Yii application through their recommended APIs. However, because in ActiveRecord requires a primary key to be set in order to function properly (it has to know what fields are the unique identifiers of the record), i'm stuck manually setting these on every model class I create. (The driver can be viewed at https://github.com/ExchangeCore/yii2-progress-driver/tree/10.2.x)

What I'd like to know is if I have overlooked some method or SYSPROGRESS table (or other ODBC function) that might actually have what fields are primary keys. I have some hope for the SYSINDEXES table, but i'm not sure how to properly identify which index is the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_file._prime-index is the RECID of the _index record that describes the index marked as "primary".

It may, or may not, be unique (that isn't a requirement).

I'm not a SQL guy (nor do I play one on TV) but this 4GL code will find the primary index for the "activity" table (if you have such a table), tell you if it is unique and list the fields that make up the index:

```
find _file no-lock where _file-name = "activity".

find _index no-lock where recid( _index ) = _file._prime-index no-error.

if available _index then
  do:
    display _index._unique.
    for each _index-field no-lock where _index-field._index-recid = recid( _index ):
      find _field no-lock where recid( _field ) = _index-field._field-recid.
      display _field-name.
    end.
  end.
```

Comment: This is good, those tables are accessible to me and it looks like I'll just have a bit of code to translate over to sql / php. I'll come back and update once I've had a chance to run it through an test it.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the help Tom. Something to note for others who stumble across this is that odbc uses `rowid` instead of `recid( table )`. Sort of a side note is that the function I wrote to find it didn't perform overly well (I imagine this is related to using rowid), taking around 50-80 ms per primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Progress DBs don't have a "primary key" - the closest you can come to a PK is to use a unique index on that table.

If you're looking in the _Index table for a given _File._file-name, you want a record where _Unique is true.

Comment: I guess I find this hard to believe / odd since the JDBC has a DatabaseMetaData method called `getPrimaryKeys`and it's description says "Gets a description of a
table’s primary key
columns."  I was also under the impression that you can designate a key as primary

Comment: Progress lacks "foreign keys" in the sense that SQL databases usually mean.  Especially any implication that they are a "constraint" or are automatically enforced in some way.  Progress does support indexes and an index can be marked as "primary".  Marking an index as "primary" is a tie-breaker for the 4gl optimizer and is the default sort order but is otherwise mostly meaningless.

Comment: @TomBascom OpenEdge seems to support and respect foreign key through SQL Engine. Understandably, comment above were made more than a year ago. If someone drops by these comments, perhaps they can review https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/#page/dmsdv/foreign-key-constraint.html